# File path not working for move_uploaded_path

Tags: php

```
$songDestination= dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/music/$songFilename";
```

This above code returns the following on local machine and server. The application works fine on localhost but could not move a file on the server.

**Server**

```
/home/kodina/yu.kodina.com/music/adekunleGOLD - Sade-240517010741pm1495627661.mp3
```

**Local**

```
C:\wamp\www\kodinaapp\music\Abdulala ft. Oritsefemi - Okamafo-240517025333pm1495630413.mp3
```

The file gets uploaded on localhost successfully but doesn't work on the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
$songDestination= realpath(__DIR__ . "/../music/" . $songFilename);
```

Comment: Thanks... But that didn't work. it returned "Error Occured"